# Tinymce version 4.1.6 with file_browser_callback how to transfer selected image of popup back to original window

Tags: jquery, jsp, tinymce

I am using tinymce version 4.1.6. I wish to implement file browser. I followed the instructions found here http://michaelbudd.org/tutorials/view/2/creating-a-custom-file-browser-for-tinymce. I created a popup and everything. 
     Then on image click i need to take back the selected image's url to the original window and here is where my problem is. In this tutorial i see that in order to transfer data from tinemce to popup and vise versa I need to use tiny_mce_popup.js. And here is where my proble begins. In TinyMCE 4.1.6 development package i found this script inside \plugins\compat3x. In the package TinyMCE 4.1.6 which has i guess the non development version there is no such java script.
      So my question is, has something elese replaced the tiny_mce_popup.js in this version or is should simple copy paste the compat3x folder into the plugins of TinyMCE 4.1.6 package i have downloaded?

-Sorry if my question is stupid but it is the first time i use this plugin-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish i read more carefully...
The answer is here:
http://michaelbudd.org/tutorials/view/28/building-custom-file-browser-for-tinymce-version-4

```
             var args    = top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.getParams();
             win         = (args.window);
             input       = (args.input);
             win.document.getElementById(input).value = '/assets/clientAssets/' + $(this).data('filename');
             top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
```

I do not know how this works... but it works...